# Ubuntu Freezes on booting from drive

Tags: boot, usb, freeze

I am attempting to install Ubuntu on my HP Laptop 14-cf1xxx. I have tried both Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.04.3. I followed the guide on the Ubuntu website (although I used Rufus to create the USB stick. When I boot from the stick to try or install Ubuntu, the loading screen freezes after about 15 seconds. Initially, when it was in the command line, it said, "SGX disabled by BIOS", but after some research, I changed the SGX settings to Enabled, which made that message disappear.

Processor: Intel Core i5-8265U
Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 620